# QED Feynman graph Coordinate space doubt

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

So I know that there are the Feynman rules to transform mathematical equation into graphs but to me it's not too much clear when I should draw the graph vertically or horizontally i.e. how I determine when the propagator  moves instantly in time (so it's  a vertical straight/wavy line depending on the particle) or moves instatly in space (so it's a horizontal straight/wavy line).
I'm currently using a convention where time flow from left to right horizontally.
Like an example could be the Bhabha scattering when I want to compute the 2nd order S-matrix I should get one "vertical" Feynman graph (where x1 and x2 which are the vertixes are one on top of the other and the photon moves vertical so it's constant in time) and one which is "horizontal", I know how to identify which part of the fermionic fields corresponds to which particle (like negative energy or positive energy associates with electron or positron in this case)

I hope that what I wrote it's understandable

Like why in this case it is correct to use an horizontal line for the propagator (it's one of the  graph in the bhabha).
Also I'm using Wick theorem to get from the time order product to the propagators and this graphs

[image]

Comment: The vertical and horizontal graphs are two completely different processes, your interpretation of what processes each stand for depends on which direction time flows in your diagrams.

Comment: You draw every possible Feynman diagram consistent with the external states and sum them, to compute the probability amplitude of the process "'in state' transitions to 'out state.'"

Comment: Taking into account that emission of a particle/antiparticle should stand on the right (with my time convention) since it's his final state, right?